# PCManFM reverts back to icon view even after setting default to list view

Tags: pcmanfm

I have configured PCManFM to use "list" view by default; however, it reverts back to "icon" view on its own.

This is my configuration:

~/.config/pcmanfm/default/pcmanfm.conf

```
[config]
bm_open_method=0

[volume]
mount_on_startup=1
mount_removable=1
autorun=1

[ui]
always_show_tabs=0
max_tab_chars=32
win_width=636
win_height=1060
splitter_pos=385
media_in_new_tab=0
desktop_folder_new_win=0
change_tab_on_drop=1
close_on_unmount=1
focus_previous=0
side_pane_mode=hidden;places
view_mode=list
show_hidden=0
sort=name;ascending;
toolbar=newtab;navigation;home;
show_statusbar=1
pathbar_mode_buttons=0
```

Shortly thereafter,  it turns into this:

```
[config]
bm_open_method=0

[volume]
mount_on_startup=1
mount_removable=1
autorun=1

[ui]
always_show_tabs=0
max_tab_chars=32
win_width=836
win_height=1030
splitter_pos=1
media_in_new_tab=0
desktop_folder_new_win=0
change_tab_on_drop=1
close_on_unmount=1
focus_previous=0
side_pane_mode=places
view_mode=icon
show_hidden=0
sort=name;ascending;
toolbar=newtab;navigation;home;
show_statusbar=1
pathbar_mode_buttons=0
```

View mode gets changed to icon.

I even tried setting the file to be immutable :) and ... no dice (I closed all running instances).  Is PCManFM respecting the configuration, or is there some configuration file floating around somewhere else?

Comment: Your configuration works for me.

Comment: What version of pcmanfm are you on?  I am using x11-misc/pcmanfm-1.3.1:0 (funtoo).

Comment: I am using version 1.3.1 from Arch Linux.

Comment: Interesting, it shouldn't matter, but my rootfs is squashfs with an overlayfs backing store.  Would it depend on any other libraries like libfm?